# Should I include a variable in a model for predicting the target variable, if I find the relationship between them is not significant?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-transformation, dataset

I came across the fact that there is a difference between, predictor variables and target variables. Using bi-variate analysis I found that an independent variable(say X) does not have a significant relationship with dependent variable(target variable - say Y). I want to do prediction for Y. Should I include X in the model?  This may be a basic question. As I am new to data science,  I am asking this.

Please also tell me the difference between independent variables and predictors.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the relationship between variables $X$ and $Y$ comes out to be non-significant in a simple model

$
Y = B_0 + B_1 X,
$

it may become statistically significant after adding predictor $Z$. In other words, coefficient estimate $B_1$ may be statistically significant in model

$
Y = B_0 + B_1 X + B_2 Z.
$

If you cannot utilize too many predictors because of the small sample size, add them in a stepwise fashion using *forward stepwise selection*.